# Outlook 2011 Search Email

Tags: ms-office

How can search email in outlook?
my outlook seems didn't have search bar like in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jbRYk_Cc0U

Here is screenshot of my Outlook:

[image]

As you can see, my outlook didn't have search bar on top right like in the video.

I use outlook 2011 version 14.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show your search bar by right clicking your top bar (just at the text "Inbox") and select to show symbols, then also the search bar will appear.

[image: screendump]

(don't mind I'm using a swedish version of Outlook)

Comment: Nope i didn't have it. as screenshot i attached, that is the rightest corner. And it's empty @_@

Comment: Don't you get a context menu when right-clicking?

Comment: ah i see. i hide the toolbar for search @_@

Answer (score 0):

After the above steps answered by **jtheman**, the below screen will be appearing.

[image]

After appearing the “**Search**” tab, click on it and just below of the tab all items will display as: *folder, sub-folder, All Mail, All Items, Subjects,From, Attachments, Send To*  etc. accordingly you can select any of your required items from the list.

[image: nter image description here]

Hope, it will make your query easier.